# Groovy java.sql.Timestamp.toString() to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: groovy, simpledateformat

I have this problem converting `java.sql.Timestamp.toString` back to `java.sql.Timestamp`. Given `element = "2012-08-01 00:00:00.0"` and using the code below would return a `ParseException` telling that `element` is an `Unparseable date`.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Timestamp string_timestamp(String element) {        
  if(!date)
    return null 
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
  // error lies here! //
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date)
  return new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime())
}
```

Is there a way to convert `java.sql.Timestamp.toString()` back to `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Date is a bad idea. Date does not handle TimeZone format etc well. See if you can use Calendar Object. Also note that something like date.getYear() will give you 2012-1900 and not the year as you expect. I gave you an example using Date below :a

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

class ABC {

public Timestamp string_timestamp(String element) throws Exception  {        
  //if(!element)
    //return null; 
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
  // error lies here! //
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(element);
  return new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ABC a = new ABC();
  System.out.println(" Value = " + a.string_timestamp("2012-08-01 01:12:56.0"));
}
}
```

Comment: Your input is "2012-08-01 00:00:00.0" correct? Your SimpleDateFormatter is different from what you are using. I will post the code in a few minutes.

Comment: @DrJava added the code.. also add try catch properly to correctly catch exceptions and also the null checks. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should simplify your method to be more groovyish. Use the `Date` class with the groovy extensions.

```
def string_timestamp(element) {
    def date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', element)
    return new Timestamp(date.time)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I may be a little late to the party, however I stumbled onto this and thought I'd give my two cents.

The Java `Timestamp` object has a `static valueOf(String s)` method.

Per the API:

```
static Timestamp    valueOf(String s)
Converts a String object in JDBC timestamp escape format to a Timestamp value.
```

Note: the string needs to be in JDBC format... So if you parse the date to a different format, you may need to parse it back before calling `Timestamp.valueOf(element)`.

link to api: [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)